# Why can't I OAuth2 authenticate with WordPress.com using oauth2 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, wordpress, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm trying to write a background job that creates blog posts in WordPress.com and I'm trying to get OAuth2 authentication to work.

I created a user, an application password for a user, and a WordPress.com app (client id and secret) and then I wrote this code:

```
puts "Username: #{Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.username}"
puts "Password: #{Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.password}"
puts "Application Password: #{Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.app_pass}"
auth_token = "#{Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.username}:#{Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.app_pass}"
puts "Auth token: #{auth_token.inspect}"
auth_token = Base64.strict_encode64(auth_token)
puts "Auth token: #{auth_token.inspect}"
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.client_id,
  Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.client_secret,
  site: "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token/"
)
client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: "https://unbrea.ch/")
client.password.get_token(
  Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.username,
  Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.password,
  headers: { "Authorization" => "Basic #{auth_token}" }
)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
/home/pupeno/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/oauth2-2.0.6/lib/oauth2/client.rb:139:in `request': invalid_client: The required "client_id" parameter is missing. (OAuth2::Error)
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The required \"client_id\" parameter is missing."}
```

but I am specifying the `client_id` when I create the `OAuth2::Client` object. Why am I getting that error?

Comment: https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/client.rb#L139

Comment: It's basic, but I'm guessing you've tested that `Rails.application.credentials.wordpress&.client_id` actually returns a value, and does that value have to be a string?